# GDB output problems after installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly

I installed gdb because it was telling me that gdb was not found when I tried to run my .asm file. Since it got installed and I shouldn't expect 'gdb not found' I ended up with the whole copyright license and stuff whenever I run my code. Did I install it incorrectly? I used "$ sudo apt-get install gdb" in terminal.

```
rm: cannot remove '*.o': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '*.lis': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '*.out': No such file or directory
compile driver.cpp using the g++ compiler standard 2017
compile isFloat.cpp using the g++ compiler standard 2017
Assemble compare.asm
Link object files using the gcc Linker standard 2017
Run the Float Program:
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--q
Quit
Script file has terminated.
```

Comment: What command did you run?  `gdb ./a.out` should run it on an executable produced by GCC or `ld`.  Did you perhaps run `gdb foo.asm` and it treated your assembly source file as a script for GDB commands?  GDB is just a debugger for programs that have already been built, not an IDE.

Comment: I was running `gdb ./final.out` on my r.sh file. But that makes sense. I didn't know what gdb was previously. Thank you.

Comment: `gdb ./final.out` is something you run on its own.  You don't run it *on* something else.  I guess you mean you ran `gdb ./final.out r.sh` or something?  Or piped or redirected the script to its standard input?  Or you ran it *from* the script with its stdin not coming from the terminal, so it just printed its splash message and exited on empty input.

Comment: Well to be exact. I ran `sh r.sh` and my code contained `gbd ./final.out` Sorry for the confusion. I just began this class and I wasn't following along well with instructor.

Comment: That should work if you run that `sh` command from a terminal.